# Angularjs service doesn't work in run() method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I got a simple get and set service in my angular app, that stores data from a $http request, but for some reason it just doesn't seem to work in angular's run() method. I'm not sure what am doing wrong.

my service

```
app.factory('sessionService', function() {
    var user_info = {};

    return {
        set: function(value) {
            user_info = value;
        },
        get: function() {
            return user_info;
        }
    };
});
```

my run method

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', 'sessionService',
    function($rootScope, $location, Auth, sessionService) {

        var routespermission = ['/dashboard', '/create']; //route that require login
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            if (routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) != -1) {
                Auth.check({
                    type: 'checkSession'
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.status === false) {
                        $location.path('/user/login');
                    } else {
                        sessionService.set(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

trying to access the data in my controller

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'sessionService',
    function($scope, $location, sessionService) {

        $scope.user_info = sessionService.get();
        console.log($scope.user_info);

        $scope.create_review = function() {

        }

    }
]);
```

when I console log the service in my controller, it return an empty object. I don't getany error, so not sure where i went wrong

Comment: Well, it's async, so it's not guaranteed to be done until the logging. Try to place a `console.log('in set function')` as well and see what happens first.

Comment: you're right, I put console.log in my set function, i like you suggested. the console log run after it reach the controller.

Comment: You can place this run block content inside of another module and require it for `app` module. According to the documentation, run blocks of required modules execute before the run block of the requiring module, so that might be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

you should inject $route dependency in app.run for '$routeChangeStart' to work.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location','$route', 'Auth', 'sessionService',
function($rootScope, $location,$route, Auth, sessionService) {

    var routespermission = ['/dashboard', '/create']; //route that require login
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        if (routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) != -1) {
            Auth.check({
                type: 'checkSession'
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.status === false) {
                    $location.path('/user/login');
                } else {
                    sessionService.set(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

]);